# Building Windows server based Docker image in Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: windows, docker, bamboo

In a corporate devstack I have access to an Atlassian Bamboo, version 9.2.9 build 90208 - 21 Dec 23.

Is it possible, and if yes how, to build a new Docker image from

```
mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
```

?

On my laptop, where runs a Windows 11, and after switching in Docker Desktop to Windows containers, I was able to build such an image. But now I need to create a Bamboo build plan where I have to build the same image.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Just put the call in your CI pipeline and have it run on a Windows build agent where Docker for Windows is available.